# How does dask work for larger than memory datasets

Tags: python, dask

Would anyone be able to tell me how [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/#) works for larger than memory dataset in simple terms. For example I have a dataset which is 6GB and 4GB RAM with 2 Cores. How would dask go about loading the data and doing a simple calculation such as sum of a column.

Does dask **automatically** check the size of the memory and chunk the dataset to smaller than memory pieces. Then, once requested to compute bring chunk by chunk into memory and do the computation using each of the available cores. Am I right on this.

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "dataset" you are apparently referring to a dataframe. Let's consider two file formats from which you may be loading: CSV and parquet.

- For CSVs, there is no inherent chunking mechanism in the file, so you, the user, can choose the bytes-per-chunk appropriate for your application using `dd.read_csv(path, blocksize=..)`, or allow Dask to try to make a decent guess; "100MB" may be a fine size to try.
- For parquet, the format itself has internal chunking of the data, and Dask will make use of this pattern in loading the data

In both cases, each worker will load one chunk at a time, and calculate the column sum you have asked for. Then, the loaded data will be discarded to make space for the next one, only keeping the results of the sum in memory (a single number for each partition). If you have two workers, two partitions will be in memory and processed at the same time. Finally, all the sums are added together.

Thus, each partition should comfortably fit into memory - not be too big - but the time it takes to load and process each should be much longer than the overhead imposed by scheduling the task to run on a worker (the latter <1ms) - not be too small.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the elaboration.

Comment: Would you say that this answers your question? If you have suggestions on how the documentation could be clearer, please post on the issue tracker.